# How to get and change the text in a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button with the class of

```
button.btn.btn-default.check-all
```

how do I find this button, get the text it says and change it with a find?

I tried something like this but not sure if it works

```
var r = $("button").find("check-all");
```

Comment: `button.btn.btn-default.check-all` is this the class name of your button?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you have a button with multiple classes and you want to select the element based on all the classes. Simply use the following selector

```
$('button.btn.btn-default.check-all')
```

You can get the text by

```
$('button.btn.btn-default.check-all').text()
```

And can update by

```
$('button.btn.btn-default.check-all').text('your_updated_text');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like:

```
var element = $('button.btn.btn-default.check-all');

//save text in prevText
var prevText = element.text();

//now, change it!
element.text('text-changed');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using class names to get an element might not be a good solution. My solution would be to use `id` attribute and use this `id` attribute to get the correct element.

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/ded4fs6m/)

**HTML**

```
<button id="my-button" name="buttonName" onclick="change()">Hi</button>
```

and **JS**

```
alert(document.getElementById('my-button').innerHTML);
function change(){
    document.getElementById('my-button').innerHTML='hello';
}
```

What I have done here is, used `document.getElementById('my-button').innerHTML` which gets the text of the button using `document.getElementById()`. The same thing can be used to set the text in a button.

Answer (score 0):

This question lead to basic skills in jQuery. I truly recommande that you could find out jQuery Api documentation and read deeply into it. You can get a very good view of jQuery thus you can do much better and efficient in your work.

Here is the link that may help you with this question.

https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
https://api.jquery.com/category/attributes/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery `:contains()` psuedo selector to create a variable that will pinpoint the button with the specified text. It can be any text, but be cautious if you have buttons with similar text because the return is not an exact match (to avoid this only input/search text that you know is unique to the button).

`var r = $("button:contains('check-all')");`

To change the text with the newly created variable you can use the jQuery `.text()` method.

`r.text('check-none');`

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/1h33m41f/)

[:contains() jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)